# Circular UIView achieved with cornerRadius looks blocky

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

In my application, I use`cornerRadius` to apply a circular mask effect to a `UIView`.

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = view.frame.height / 2
view.clipsToBounds = true
```

However, when I use this method, the result looks blocky. I enlarged this example of the issue, so the issue can be seen better (especially on the top):

[image: An example of the blockiness with a plain black image.]

What causes this and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `UIView`'s frame size: change every value to a whole number, so the graphics engine can calculate the image with a perfect result.